# How to move a cutout in GIMP

Tags: gimp, images, transparency

I have a black and white image with a transparent background. I have the numbers "190" cut out of the white area with a transparent background. The numbers aren't text, they are just holes in the image. I really want to move those numbers/holes sideways but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, this wouldn't always be possible because where there is transparency now you'll have opaque pixels after the move, and you can't invent the contents of these pixels(*). However since you state that the pixels are in a white area, we know how to plug the holes... So basically you:

- Get and save a selection on the shape of the hole
- Fill the hole
- Move the selection
- Use the selection to punch a new hole

In slow motion:

- *Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection* to get a selection on the holes (and other transparent bits)
- *Select>Invert*
- *Select>Save to channel* (this saves the selection for later)
- Re-select the layer in the layers list (because the current "drawable" has become the saved selection)
- Make a rough selection around the letters (Rectangle select or lasso)
- Bucket-fill the selection with white to fill the existing "holes". **Do not lose that selection**
- Open the Channels list, right-click the saved selection, and *Intersect with selection*. The selection should become the letters you want to move and only that, the other transparent bits being excluded.
- Start the Move tool, and select the "Move selection" mode in the Tool options (red square icon)
- Drag the letter selection to where you want the new holes to be
- In the Layers list, re-select the layer
- *Edit>Clear* (or [delete])

(*) Unless the contents is still there and the pixels are just marked transparent. Miracles happen..